# How to process separate XML elements using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am attempting to process the following XML to display each Discount record with each MerchandiseItem using XSLT:

NOTE: Each MerchandiseItem is always followed by 0 or more Discount elements

Sample XML:

```
<IBMGSA xmlns="http://www.omnicogroup.com/FPF/namespace"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <transaction>
        <MerchandiseItem Record="2">
            <Identifier>
                <SalePrc>6.14</SalePrc>
                <Quantity>1.00</Quantity>
                <NetQuantity>1.00</NetQuantity>
                <SaleQuantity>1</SaleQuantity>
                <SalePrice>6.14</SalePrice>
                <Penny>.01</Penny>
                <Zero>0.00</Zero>
                <IsVoided>0</IsVoided>
                <VoidedQuantity>0.00</VoidedQuantity>
            06</Identifier>
            <ItemCode>
                <ItemCodeGTIN14>00000000000083</ItemCodeGTIN14>
                <ItemCodeGTIN12>000000000008</ItemCodeGTIN12>
                <Sku>000000008</Sku>
                <SkuType>3</SkuType>
                <SkuByte>1</SkuByte>
                <SuppressRecord>NO</SuppressRecord>
                <ItemDescription>ZIL PLAY A-</ItemDescription>
                <ItemDescTrimmed>ZIL PLAYA-SYS</ItemDescTrimmed>
            1000000000000000000083</ItemCode>
            <Department>
                <DeptSuppress>YES</DeptSuppress>
            182</Department>
            <ItemAmount>
                <NegativeTransaction>0</NegativeTransaction>
                <ItemAmount>7.68</ItemAmount>
                <ItemDiscountCode>2</ItemDiscountCode>
                <ItemDiscountAmount>1.54</ItemDiscountAmount>
                <ItemDiscountPercent>20.0</ItemDiscountPercent>
                <ItemAmt>7.68</ItemAmt>
                <ItemDisAmt>6.14</ItemDisAmt>
            </ItemAmount>   <!-- Added by edit -->
        </MerchandiseItem>
        <Discount Record="3">
            <Identifier>10</Identifier>
            <DiscountCode>2</DiscountCode>
            <DiscountAmount>
                <DiscountAmountType>PE</DiscountAmountType>
                <DiscountQuantity>1</DiscountQuantity>
                <NegativeTransaction>0</NegativeTransaction>
                <DiscountAmount>1.54</DiscountAmount>
                <TaxExemptAmount>0.00</TaxExemptAmount>
                <ABSDiscountAmt>1.54</ABSDiscountAmt>
            154</DiscountAmount>
            <DiscountPercent>
                <DiscountPercent>20.0</DiscountPercent>
            200</DiscountPercent>
        </Discount>
        <Discount Record="4">
            <Identifier>10</Identifier>
            <DiscountCode>25</DiscountCode>
        </Discount>
        ...
        ...
        ...
    </transaction>
</IBMGSA>                   <!-- Added by edit -->
```

How could I traverse the `DiscountItem` elements while iterating through each MerchandiseItem element given that the `DiscountItem` elements always comes after the `MerchandiseItem` element and needs to be associated/displayed only with that `MerchandiseItem`?

I need the output to be as follows (referencing this sample XML) - thank you for reformatting!
Thank you - the correct HTML output (version 5) should be:

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
ZIL PLAY A-                                             
00000000000083    1 @ 7.68                   7.68                              
10  (20 %) OFF 00000000000083                1.54-
25  (5 %) OFF 00000000000083                  .31-
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

XML equivalent of output above:

```
<ItemDescription>ZIL PLAY A-</ItemDescription>
<ItemCodeGTIN14>00000000000083</ItemCodeGTIN14>    <Quantity>1.00</Quantity> @   <ItemAmount>7.68</ItemAmount>

<Identifier>10</Identifier> (<DiscountPercent>20.0 %</DiscountPercent>) OFF <ItemCodeGTIN14>00000000000083</ItemCodeGTIN14>  <DiscountAmount>1.54</DiscountAmount>-
<Identifier>25</Identifier> (<DiscountPercent>5 %</DiscountPercent>) OFF <ItemCodeGTIN14>00000000000083</ItemCodeGTIN14> <DiscountAmount>.31</DiscountAmount>-
```

Using the suggestion in comments from @michael.hor257k, I am trying to display the MerchandiseItem and Discount information using the following XSL (updated to be more clear - hopefully - of how I want to group and display the DiscountItem and MerchandiseItems listed above:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.omnicogroup.com/FPF/namespace" 
xmlns:ns1="http://www.omnicogroup.com/FPF/namespace" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
       <xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        </head>
        <body>
             <table>
               <tr>
                  <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-
              with="MerchandiseItem">

                  <b>Here is a MerchItem</b><br/> <!--Should repeat (16 times as there are 16 total MerchandiseItem elements in my XML payload. Currently -nothing is displayed and it does not appear that this for-each group is being entered at runtime)-->

                  </xsl:for-each-group>
               </tr>
          </table>
        </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but nothing is rendering using the same XML example. Are my for-each loops not referencing the MerchandiseItem/Discount groupings correctly?

Comment: What would look like your desired XML output? And what should be your HTML output version (4.0, 4.01, 5.0)? And did I add the correct closing tags to your source XML?

Comment: You say you want HTML5 output, but provide the result of `text` output. You can create the output your want by referencing the desired element with `xsl:value-of`. But do it by yourself, because your question is _unclear_.

Comment: Thank you for reformatting the XML, I have updated the description to include the expected output I am trying to achieve...hopefully this makes sense what I am trying to do.

Comment: I have provided the expected output (HTML) and XML equivalent. My question is, using the XSL for-each loop code I provided, how can I process this XML sample which has multiple MerchandiseItem elements along with associated (not structured as such) <Discount> elements in the expected format I included (HTML and XML). Thank you!

Comment: Assuming that each `MerchandiseItem` is followed by 0 to many associated `Discount` elements, you could use `<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="MerchandiseItem">` to group each item with its discounts. Then process the discounts using `xsl:for-each select="current-group()/Discount"`.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, I will try modifying my for-each loop construct to use these for-each-group and for-each select group and post back if any issues.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi - I added the XSL code I modified to use the for-each-group of the MerchandiseItem to my description (bottom above) but when I run this, no MerchandiseItem elements are displayed. Is there a problem with how I am trying to access these group'd elements? Thank you!

Comment: @michael.hor257k - Apologize for not directing my reply earlier...I attempted to use 
`<xsl:for-each-group select` - per my snippet (updated in this post). This is not rendering any output given the XML payload I included in my post. My question is can I use this for-each-group construct within my `<xsl:template match="/">` and still group and output the elements (MerchandiseItem and Discount) or do I need to utilize this for-each-group construct within `<xsl:template match="Discount">` as shown in @EdBangs example?

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what your output should look like. I would expect to see a row for each item, or perhaps for each discount?

Comment: @michael.hor257k - I would expect an output of 
    <b>Here is a MerchItem</b><br/>
for each MerchandiseItem as well - but instead, nothing is displayed in this section of my html document. NOTE: I added in what are the top 3 lines of my current XSL in my snippet. I will try and update the fiddler codespace with my example XML payload and run my XSL snippet to see if anything gets displayed...maybe something in my XSL is interfering with this group construct.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample XSLT 3 (I think I have used no XSLT 3 features so should work with an XSLT 2 processor as well) stylesheet that shows how to apply `for-each-group group-starting-with` in some context to group and output the data:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
        xpath-default-namespace="http://www.omnicogroup.com/FPF/namespace"
        version="3.0">


    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>.NET XSLT Fiddle Example</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="transaction">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th/>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="MerchandiseItem">
                <tbody>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[self::Discount]">
                        <xsl:with-param name="merch-item" select="."/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </tbody>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Discount">
        <xsl:param name="merch-item"/>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" align="left" style="font-size:14px;line-height:18px;">
                <xsl:value-of select="$merch-item/ItemCode/ItemDescription"/>
                <br />
                <xsl:value-of select="$merch-item/ItemCode/ItemCodeGTIN14"/>&#160;

                <xsl:value-of select="floor($merch-item/Identifier/Quantity)"/> @ <xsl:value-of 
    select="$merch-item/ItemAmount/ItemAmount div $merch-item/Identifier/Quantity"/>

                <xsl:value-of select="Identifier, DiscountPercent/DiscountPercent"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGd3

I realize the output format is not the one you have shown but I couldn't really figure from the two different snippets which format exactly you want, the sample shows how to use the grouping construct and also process each `Discount` element in each group to output some value while allowing access to the `MerchandiseItem` starting each group so hopefully it suffices to allow you to mold that into the proper format yourself.

Comment: Hi @EdBangs - so I am trying your example Fiddler XSL and am not sure if this will work with my XSLt code. In particular, do I need to format the output using 
    <xsl:template match=...
?
Can I not just use the 
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="MerchandiseItem">

and then iterate through those group'd elements and output in formatted HTML?
 
Ex:

`<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="MerchandiseItem">
<b>Test output iterating through group</b><br/>
</xsl:for-each-group>`

Comment: @EdBangs - my question/comment relates back to my earlier example code whereby I am trying to group MerchandiseItems and iterate through them within
`<xsl:template match="/">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
.
.`

Comment: @user3093222, you said the grouping would not work for you without showing any details like minimal but complete samples of  XSLT code, HTML output you want and the one you get. I simply tried to show you a minimal context on how to use `for-each-group`, of course you can use it differently if you want to or think you have to and have grasped its concept. The shown snippet trying to put data into the `head` section of an XHTML document doesn't make any sense to me so I wrote an example putting the data into the body.

Comment: Martin - my XSLT document is 30K in size...adding it completely would not fit in this post. What I did add was a complete snippet of what my code is currently doing. I grant that my knowledge of for-each-group'ng in XSL is not anywhere near "mastery-level" and my XSL code already has a 
`<xsl:template match="/">`

Comment: I have added a more explicit snippet of how my XSL is currently structured and where exactly I need to display the MerchandiseItem and Discount line items. Please let me know if this is not clear...happy to add more detail.

Comment: @user3093222, well, if you have `xsl:template match="/"` and use the `for-each-group` in there, given the document structure you have shown, it should use `<xsl:for-each-group select="//transaction/*" group-starting-with="MerchandiseItem">` (and that also needs the `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.omnicogroup.com/FPF/namespace"` I have had in my minimal sample).

Comment: @user3093222, see it in action at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGd3/1. Although I haven't understood why you start with a `table` but don't create any table cells.

Comment: I have created a code example using my XSL snippet (listed in this posting) here:
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NJ38ZV

Note: This example contains a full XML payload sample (with 6 complete MerchandiseItem records). I am not sure why my XSL code is not producing 6 "Here is a MerchItem" table rows using this for-each-group construct?

Comment: Well, you need to select `for-each-group select="//transaction/*"`, as already said in a previous comment.

Comment: ok, adding to the Fiddler example does produce the expected number of dummy test lines based on the number of MerchandiseItems in the XML payload. For some reason though in my other test environment, nothing is getting displayed when using the for-each-group construct to group and iterate through the MerchandiseItems in my XML payload. Not sure if this is caused by the version/engine of XML/XSL my environment uses?

Comment: @user3093222, if you need help establishing whether your XSLT processor of your environment supports XSLT 2 or 3 (where `for-each-group` is supported) then you need to share as much details of that enviroment. The usual XSLT 2 or 3 processors used today are Saxon 9 standalone or in various editors/IDEs like oXygen or StylusStudio or AltovaXML in XMLSpy or with its Raptor server software. But IBM in Websphere also has XSLT 2 support I think.

Comment: thank you, I am reaching out to my devops./engineering teams to get this information. I think the for-each-group construct is really the only way to handle the MerchandiseItem and Discount elements with how they are structured in the payload XML? If so, we can close out this question going with this solution (for-each-group). Thank you!